# How to install globally installed npm packages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, package, global

I wanted to try Vue js but it seems to be very hard for me to import it to my project. I there a way where you can install the dependencies without using internet (downloading again) which is already installed globally.
Vue 2 is installed globally and I will be using `vue init`, but it seems that `vue init` is installing the Vue again from the internet. I want it to take the dependencies from the already installed (globally) and put it in my folder so that I dont use internet.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Oh my god! I resolved this myself, I tried the `vue init` again and it seems to be working good without internet. Thanks to all...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new project dir to store the globally installed package (copy from the installation folder) and after that copy process make a zip of it so that it can be used again, then you have to config some of the files for your project needs.

Comment: Can you please tell more elaborately about this answer, Im not able to understand, thanks.

Comment: it is actual  create a empty dir and add package.json ,other config files and run npm install when  vue init.So,you can a father project installed the neccessary modules.Copy the father project and modify some config files.It is actually a new project without instal again

Answer (score -1):

Try install localy and use command

```
npx vue <command>
```

Also check **package.json** in your project

Comment: Can you please explain on how it works, cuz I dont want to use my internet again on downloading these packages.

Comment: @loliallen I dont think you've understood the question well